# multiple popup manage or it's say Popup over popup in swift

Tags: ios, swift, popup

i have 5 type of popUp for different action on each popup. after the submit popup A dismiss that popup and open new popup on main details screen. i face the problem was that if i am remove popup A from AviewController that time not open popup B on mainViewController .

i have multiple popup manage here same like this. like A , B, C , D, all are open from mainViewController and also individual popup own class and manage APIs and all.

any one have nay idea to manage this?

OPEN LIKE THIS :

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test1") as! Test1
        self.addChild(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Close POPUP LIKE THIS :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
```

OPEN LIKE THIS :

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test1") as! Test1
        self.addChild(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Close POPUP LIKE THIS :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
```

here i try all github reference but not any that popup open after first popup is close.(need to click open secound popup open).

Thanks in advance